# finding mistake in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

I strated building a site in HTML and SQL.
Here is the code:
Login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>login</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
<iframe src="menu.html" width="670px" height="170px"  frameBorder="0"     style="position:absolute;right:23em">
</iframe>
<img src="design\login2.jpg" height="300px"  id="frc">
<form id="lgin" runat="server">
<table class="regtext">
    <tr class="sec">
        <td>username</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="filld" </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="filld" </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" id="legbtn" value="login" />
</table>
   <%=status %>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the code for server side (C#):
Login.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string status = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string userName = Request.Form["userName"];
        string password = Request.Form["pass"];

        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName='{0}' ", userName);
        sql += string.Format("AND password='{0}'", password);

        if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist("Database.mdf", sql))
        {
            Session["userName"] = userName;
            sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName='{0}' ", userName);
            sql += string.Format("AND admin='{0}'", true);

            if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist("Database.mdf", sql))
            {
                Session["admin"] = "admin";
                Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("ForRegistered.aspx");
        }
        else
            status = "error!";



        }
    }
}
```

The error is "status does not exist in current context". Where is the problem?

Comment: What happens if I provide `' OR 1=1 --` for the username

Comment: What @Chris is actually saying is [`parameterize your queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) or use an ORM.

Comment: Well yeah Chase, but sometimes its better to learn by figuring it out.

Comment: StackOverflow is a great place to learn things like this. I'd rather mention it here instead of have someone experience the mistake in the wild.

Comment: Where can I parameterize the queries? I have thw following file connecting to the database: http://he.scribd.com/doc/132048575/Untitled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page inherits Default2 and not login. Change the inherits in the page directive on your aspx page to inherit the correct class and you should be in better shape.